# Upper right triangle with check-sign

Tags: css

I am trying to find a better way to create an upper right triangle with a check-sign on it with CSS:

[image: Result of CSS]

So far, I produce the triangle with three CSS-Elements:

```
.arrow_down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 200px solid transparent;
    border-right: 200px solid transparent;
    border-top: 200px solid #f00;
}

.arrow_left {
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 200px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 200px solid transparent; 
    border-right:200px solid blue; 
}

.arrow_text { 
    font-size: 180px; 
    color: white; 
    margin-top: -200px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
}
```

And i embedd the triangle accordingly like this:

```
<div id="triangle"><div class="arrow_down"></div><div class="arrow_left"><div class=arrow_text>✔</div></div></div>
```

I can't switch to an image because I need to be able to change the colors flexibly. **Is there a better ( = simpler ) way to create and embedd such a triangle with the check-sign?**

Comment: use svg, you will be able to switch colours with css

Comment: Thanks, i did not know this .. I'll google for it.

Comment: If you want to continue use css, use just one div for the arrow, and use the attribute border-top-color and border-right-color

Comment: Thanks Paolo, that's an improvement already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another one div variation ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjpK6/1/)):

```
.arrow {
    width: 400px;    
    height: 400px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    font: bold 200px/1 sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow::before {
    content: '';
    border: 200px solid;
    border-color: #f00 #00f rgba(0,0,255,0) rgba(255,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 because your fiddle with only one div is eerily similar to my own fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Ilya, I'll use your suggestion!